Node.JS console.log output is not shown in Windows cmd
I'd like to add some console.log debugging code into my TS script and it is not displayed currently.
I've added the following to package.json:
"start": "dotenv -- node --import tsx -e 'require(\"./path/to/my.ts\").myFunction()'",

and run it like npm run start.
Moreover, the simplest test commands give me no output both:
npx ts-node -e 'console.log("test")'

and
node --import tsx -e 'console.log("test")'

What could be the reason and should I perform some setup first?

Node v20.14.0
NPM 10.2.0
Windows 10 Pro x64

Have you checked the result of the command? Maybe it's crashing?

A couple of simplest commands in the end doesn't seem crashed. BTW, checked this and "echo %errorlevel%" gives 0. Same commands work as expected in WSL on the same machine. Only pure Windows has the issue.
